# Can't use @ObservedObject on real iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui, xcode11

i can't get my view to appear when it uses `@ObservedObject` in it. The app crashed when i try to present it and i get this error:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x9)

The app runs fine on the simulator. It only crashes on my

**iPhone 6s iOS 13 beta 6**

**Xcode beta 5**

That's my basic code:

```swift
class NetworkManager: ObservableObject {

}

struct ContentView : View {
    @ObservedObject var networkManager: NetworkManager = NetworkManager()

    var body: some View {
        Text("Hi Stack")
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
#endif
```

Comment: Your `NetworkManager` doesn't conform to `ObservableObject`? [Here](https://github.com/dtroupe18/SwiftUI-MVVM-Combine) is a sample repo that uses MMVM and Combine. I think you just need to add `let objectWillChange = PassthroughSubject<NetworkManager,Never>()` and call it whenever that whenever the data is set.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This isn't a problem with not conforming to `ObservableObject`. The code you provided works in the canvas and in the simulator, and should also work on the device. I have already come across this issue with iOS 13 Beta 6 in my own project and have spent a lot of time troubleshooting.

Other things (such as calling `self.presentationMode.value.dismiss()` to dismiss a modal view) are also currently broken when running projects built with Xcode Beta 5 on devices running iOS 13 Beta 6. There have been issues with previous betas of Xcode not working on newer betas of iOS, and this may be the same issue.

I would suggest that you wait until Xcode Beta 6 is released to make any significant structural changes to your code, as iOS 13 Beta 6 may have been developed in anticipation of handling changes that will be made in Xcode Beta 6.

That being said, if you absolutely must make changes to workaround this issue in the meantime, I've found that using `@EnvironmentObject` instead of `@ObservedObject` fixes this issue. In your example, that would mean declaring your property like this:

```swift
@EnvironmentObject private var networkManager: NetworkManager
```

Then, when you create your view, you can pass a `NetworkManager` as an environment object like this:

```swift
ContentView()
    .environmentObject(NetworkManager())
```

Comment: You can fix the presentationModes dismiss by calling .wrappedValue instead of .value

Comment: I never even thought to try that. Thanks!

Comment: I have been trying to Google this issue for SO LONG! Thank you!

Comment: XCode 11 beta 6 does not solve the issue on my iPhone iOS 13 beta 7.  I tried the EnvironmentObject solution but it only created other runtime errors.

Comment: @K.Law If you’re experiencing crashes that aren’t solved by removing instances of `@ObservedObject`, then the issue you’re having is probably something else entirely. I would suggest you post a new question so we can see what errors you’re coming across.

Comment: The problems are caused by the ObservedObject.  The EnviromentObject didn't help me, it produces this error:  Thread 1: Fatal error: No observable object of type MYLocationManager.Type found..  I just installed iOS 13 beta 8, and the error remains the same.

Comment: @K.Law I get that you're getting an error related to `@ObservedObject`, but that's a different error than what the original poster of this question was experiencing. I see that you're coming here from a question you already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57610220/swiftui-with-core-location-as-observableobject-crashes). Can you update that question with the code that is causing that error?

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was the same error.  However, all the code is there, along with the specific line the error is appearing on.  Thanks for looking into it.  If you could comment on that question, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 3):

Update your project using Xcode 11 beta 6. This fixes the issue. I can confirm it with an app I am working on.  Finally came out today!

Comment: Are you running the app on a phone?  I have code that will run on an iPad but not a phone.

Comment: Yes it does run on a phone. I am testing on an iPhone 8 with the beta installed.