# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x9) when trying to run my app on a physical device

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, xcode11

I'm trying to run an app on a physical device, but I have a

> "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x9)"

in the `AppDelegate.Swift` file.

I'm having trouble fixing the issue, even finding its origin.

I'm using Xcode11 beta 5. The app uses SwiftUI.

I turned on the `Zombie Object` under the `Diagnostic` tab when running the app.

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate { // Can't pass this line

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:  [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
    }

}
```

Let me know if something else would help.

Also I'm a beginner.

Thanks!

Comment: A few questions. First, what beta version of iOS 13 are you using? It should be beta 5 also. Next, Could you start up a new project (beta 5 on both ends) and see if you still get this error? You should get "hello world". Both of these are common mistakes - no problem. Good luck!

Comment: I’m assuming you’re using Xcode Beta 5 and iOS 13 Beta 6. In which case, your issue probably has to do with using `@ObservedObject`. I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57421554/11762053). Let me know if that helps. If it does, we can mark your question as a duplicate of that.

Comment: @dfd I'm using all the latest beta  (iOS 13 beta 6, masOS Catalina beta 5, Xcode beta 5). I have this error on apps that uses Observable Object. I'm going to try changing them.

Comment: @graycampbell Thanks! I searched and couldn't find a similar issue. I'm going to try the fix proposed on the thread and see it from their.

Comment: @graycampbell It did help. Thanks a lot!