# SwiftUI with Core Location as ObservableObject crashes

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, core-location

I am trying to use Core Location to get the CLRegionState to update elements in a SwiftUI app.  I am using XCode 11 beta 6 and have iOS 13 beta 7 on my device.

There are two problems that I can see:

1. The app crashes and the error `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS` appears on line `147` (...ScrollView {... )
2. The CLRegionState is never called or does not update.

I am basing this off of Paul Hudson's tutorial on SwiftUI Beacon Detector (which I have not been able to make work either), and modifying it to use CLRegionState instead of beacon proximity .

Here is the code:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import CoreLocation
import Combine

class MYLocationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
      
  var locationManager: CLLocationManager?
  var willChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
  var lastRegionState = CLRegionState.unknown
        
  override init() {
    super.init()
    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager?.delegate = self
    locationManager?.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
  }
        
  func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    checkLocationAuthorization()
  }
        
  func update(state: CLRegionState) {
    lastRegionState = state
    willChange.send(())
  }
        
  func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    guard let location = locations.last else { return }

    print("Your location is \(location)")
    update(state: .unknown)
  }
        
  func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    print(error)
  }
        
  func startScanning() {         
    // temporary coordinates
    var workCoordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
      return CLLocationCoordinate2D(
        latitude: 43.486525,
        longitude: -11.912542)
    }
            
    var homeCoordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2D(
                                  latitude: 43.499541,
                                  longitude: -11.875079)
            
    let workRegion: CLCircularRegion = CLCircularRegion(center: workCoordinates, radius: 100, identifier: "Work")
            
    let homeRegion: CLCircularRegion = CLCircularRegion(center: homeCoordinates, radius: 100, identifier: "Home")
            
    locationManager!.startMonitoring(for: workRegion)
    locationManager!.startMonitoring(for: homeRegion)
    locationManager!.requestState(for: workRegion)
    locationManager!.requestState(for: homeRegion)
  }
        
  func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didDetermineState state: CLRegionState, for region: CLRegion) {
    switch state {
      case .inside:
        switch region.identifier {
      case "Work":
        print("You are at work")
      case "Home":
        print("You are at home")
      default:
        print("unknown")
    }
      default:
      break
    }
  }
        
  func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {       
    switch region.identifier {
      case "Work":
        print("Work**********")
        //self.taskTypeSegCtrl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
      case "Home":
        print("Home*********8")
        //self.taskTypeSegCtrl.selectedSegmentIndex = 1
      default:
        break
    }
  }
        
  func checkLocationAuthorization() {
    switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
      case .authorizedWhenInUse:
        startScanning()
        break
      case .authorizedAlways:
        startScanning()
        break
      case .denied:
        // show an alert instructing them howto turn on permissions
        break
      case .notDetermined:        
        print("Location authorization is not determined.")
        locationManager!.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        break
      case .restricted:
        break
      @unknown default:
        fatalError()
    }
  }
}


struct ContentView: View {
  @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
        
  @FetchRequest(entity: Task.entity(),
                      sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(
                        keyPath: \Task.name, ascending: true)])
  var tasks: FetchedResults<Task>
        
  var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        
  @ObservedObject var location: MYLocationManager = MYLocationManager()
        
  @State private var taskName = ""
  @State private var taskType = 0
  @State private var selectedTask = ""
  @State private var numberOfTaps = 0
  @State private var regionState = CLRegionState.unknown
        
  var body: some View {
            
    ScrollView {
      VStack {
        TextField("Enter a task name", text: $taskName)
                        .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                    Picker(selection: $taskType, label: Text("Task type")) {
                        Text("Work").tag(1)
                        Text("Home").tag(2)
                    }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                    
        Text(selectedTask)
                    
        Button(action: {
          let task = Task(context: self.managedObjectContext)
          task.name = self.taskName
          task.type = Int16(self.taskType)
           do {
             try self.managedObjectContext.save()
          } catch {
            // handle the Core Data error
          }
           self.taskName = ""
        }) {
            Text("Save Task")
        }.padding()
                    
         Button(action: {
             if self.numberOfTaps < self.tasks.count {
               let task = self.tasks[self.numberOfTaps].name
               self.selectedTask = task ?? "No task..."
               self.numberOfTaps = self.numberOfTaps + 1
            } else {
               self.selectedTask = "No more tasks!  Have a wonderful day."
            }
          }) {
            Text("Next Task")
          }
                    
          List {
            ForEach(tasks, id: \.self) { task in
              VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 6) {
                Text(task.name ?? "Unknown")
                  .font(.headline)
                Text("Task type \(task.type)")
                  .font(.caption)
            }
          }.onDelete(perform: removeTask)
        }
      }   .frame(width: 300, height: 400, alignment: .top)
          .padding()
          .border(Color.black)
                
      if regionState == .inside {
        Text("inside")
      } else if regionState == .outside {
        Text("outside")
      } else {
        Text("unknown")
      }          
                
      Spacer()
    }
  }
        
        
  func removeTask(at offsets: IndexSet) {
    for index in offsets {
      let task = tasks[index]
      managedObjectContext.delete(task)
      do {
        try managedObjectContext.save()
      } catch {
        // handle the Core Data error
      }
    }
  }
        
  func showTask(at offsets: IndexSet) {
    for index in offsets {
      let task = tasks[index]
      selectedTask = task.name ?? "No task..."
    }
  }
}

#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    ContentView()
  }
}
#endif
```

After implementing the changes made by Fabian, here is the content of the console log:

```
Granted: true
2019-08-22 14:30:07.051062-0600 AppName[4452:2089841] locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus)
2019-08-22 14:30:07.052803-0600 New1Thing[4452:2089841] startScanning
2019-08-22 14:30:07.054319-0600 New1Thing[4452:2089841] Current location: <+**.49945068,-***.87504490> +/- 65.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 8/22/19, 2:30:07 PM **** Daylight Time
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off I want to thank Fabian and graycampbell for their help.

Secondly, as for as I can tell @ObservableObject still does not work in iOS 13 beta 8 using XCode 11 beta 6.

Here is what worked for me:
1. I changed

```
@ObservedObject var location: MYLocationManager = MYLocationManager()
```

to:

```
@EnvironmentObject var location: MYLocationManager
```

2. In the SceneDelegate I added:

```
let myLocationManager = MYLocationManager()
```

and:

```
 window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: CoreLocationView_NeedsEnv()
            .environmentObject(myLocationManager)
```

No more crash!!

P.S. I am using Fabian's updated code.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a complete working example. There were several problems I fixed.

1. `ObservableObject` does now work with `objectWillChange` instead of `willChange`.
2. It should now update on every status change.

The updating part was not complete before (my opinion)

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreLocation
import Combine
import CoreData
import os

class MYLocationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    var locationManager: CLLocationManager?
    var objectWillChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
    @Published var lastRegionState = CLRegionState.unknown {
        willSet {
            objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }
    @Published var currentRegion: Region = .nowhereKnown {
        willSet {
            objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }

    override init() {
        super.init()
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager!.delegate = self
        locationManager!.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        fatalError("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    enum Region: String {
        case work = "Work"
        case home = "Home"
        case nowhereKnown = "Nowhere Known"
    }

    func startScanning() {
        os_log("startScanning")

        // temporary coordinates
        var workCoordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
            return CLLocationCoordinate2D(
                latitude: 43.486525,
                longitude: -11.912542)
        }

        var homeCoordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2D(
            latitude: 43.499541,
            longitude: -11.875079)

        if let currentLocation = locationManager?.location {
            os_log("Current location: %@", currentLocation.description)
            homeCoordinates = currentLocation.coordinate
        } else {
            os_log("Current location: failed")
        }

        let workRegion: CLCircularRegion = CLCircularRegion(center: workCoordinates, radius: 100, identifier: Region.work.rawValue)
        let homeRegion: CLCircularRegion = CLCircularRegion(center: homeCoordinates, radius: 100, identifier: Region.home.rawValue)

        locationManager!.startMonitoring(for: workRegion)
        locationManager!.startMonitoring(for: homeRegion)
        locationManager!.requestState(for: workRegion)
        locationManager!.requestState(for: homeRegion)
    }
}

// MARK: Authorization
extension MYLocationManager {
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        os_log("locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus)")
        checkLocationAuthorization()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        os_log("locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])")
        guard let location = locations.last else { return }
        print("Your location is \(location)")
        update(state: .unknown)
    }

    func checkLocationAuthorization() {
        switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
        case .authorizedWhenInUse:
            startScanning()
            break
        case .authorizedAlways:
            startScanning()
            break
        case .denied:
            // show an alert instructing them howto turn on permissions
            break
        case .notDetermined:

            print("Location authorization is not determined.")
            locationManager!.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
            break
        case .restricted:
            break
        @unknown default:
            fatalError()
        }
    }
}

// MARK: UI Updates
extension MYLocationManager: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    func updateCurrentRegion(region: CLRegion) {
        guard let region = Region(rawValue: region.identifier) else {
            currentRegion = .nowhereKnown
            return
        }
        currentRegion = region
    }

    func update(state: CLRegionState) {
        lastRegionState = state
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didDetermineState state: CLRegionState, for region: CLRegion) {
        self.lastRegionState = state
        updateCurrentRegion(region: region)
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {
        updateCurrentRegion(region: region)
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didExitRegion region: CLRegion) {
        updateCurrentRegion(region: region)
    }
}

struct CoreLocationView: View {
    private static func makeContainer() -> NSPersistentContainer {
        let store = NSPersistentContainer(name: "CoreLocationView")
        store.loadPersistentStores { (desc, err) in
            if let err = err {
                fatalError("core data error: \(err)")
            }
        }
        return store
    }

    let container: NSPersistentContainer

    init() {
        self.container = CoreLocationView.makeContainer()
    }

    var body: some View {
        CoreLocationView_NeedsEnv().environment(\.managedObjectContext, container.viewContext)
    }
}

struct CoreLocationView_NeedsEnv: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext

    @FetchRequest(entity: Task.entity(),
                  sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(
                    keyPath: \Task.name, ascending: true)])
    var tasks: FetchedResults<Task>

    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    @ObservedObject var location: MYLocationManager = MYLocationManager()

    @State private var taskName = ""
    @State private var taskType = 0
    @State private var selectedTask = ""
    @State private var numberOfTaps = 0
    //@State private var regionState = CLRegionState.unknown

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                TextField("Enter a task name", text: $taskName)
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                Picker(selection: $taskType, label: Text("Task type")) {
                    Text("Work").tag(1)
                    Text("Home").tag(2)
                }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())

                Text(selectedTask)

                Button(action: {
                    let task = Task(context: self.managedObjectContext)
                    task.name = self.taskName
                    task.type = Int16(self.taskType)
                    do {
                        try self.managedObjectContext.save()
                    } catch {
                        // handle the Core Data error
                    }
                    self.taskName = ""
                }) {
                    Text("Save Task")
                }.padding()

                Button(action: {
                    if self.numberOfTaps < self.tasks.count {
                        let task = self.tasks[self.numberOfTaps].name
                        self.selectedTask = task ?? "No task..."
                        self.numberOfTaps = self.numberOfTaps + 1
                    } else {
                        self.selectedTask = "No more tasks!  Have a wonderful day."
                    }
                }) {
                    Text("Next Task")
                }

                List {
                    ForEach(tasks, id: \.self) {
                        task in
                        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 6) {
                            Text(task.name ?? "Unknown")
                                .font(.headline)
                            Text("Task type \(task.type)")
                                .font(.caption)
                        }
                    }.onDelete(perform: removeTask)

                }
            }   .frame(width: 300, height: 400, alignment: .top)
                .padding()
                .border(Color.black)

            if location.lastRegionState == .inside {
                Text("inside")
            } else if location.lastRegionState == .outside {
                Text("outside")
            } else {
                Text("unknown")
            }

            Text("Where am I: \(location.currentRegion.rawValue)")


            Spacer()
        }
    }


    func removeTask(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        for index in offsets {
            let task = tasks[index]
            managedObjectContext.delete(task)
            do {
                try managedObjectContext.save()
            } catch {
                // handle the Core Data error
            }
        }
    }

    func showTask(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        for index in offsets {
            let task = tasks[index]
            selectedTask = task.name ?? "No task..."
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your work, however the app still crashes at the same place.  It works in a simulator but not on a device.

Comment: I am running it on my ipad pro directly. Did you add descriptions why location is needed? It was additionally necessary to add Location Capability. Better add the complete error with priorly printed errors.

Comment: I added the console log info to the end of my question.  Location is needed for some features of the app to work correctly.  Location permissions are allowed for this app on my device.

Comment: Please copy from there up to and including the crash please. Without it I can't see where the crash is exactly :(

Comment: The app crashes on the ScrollView line ( var body: some View {
        ScrollView {)  If I comment out the @ObservedObject line and the other dependent code that relies on it, the app runs fine.  So the problem is the ObservedObject. Have you tried running the code on a phone?

Comment: Damn a phone. I'm currently on iOS12 and so I can't test it. Can't help you there. Weird that it crashes on the `ScrollView` though. My last idea would be to remove the `List` around the `Foreach` (Scroll in scroll) but that probably won't help either.

Comment: I believe iOS and iPadOS are two different animals now.  I has to be a bug.  Thanks again for the code suggestions.  I am a fairly inexperienced programmer, so looking at your code is very helpful.  I can give you and up-vote and will mark it solved when the bug is resolved.

Comment: @K.Law Are you saying that if you remove `@ObservedObject var location: MYLocationManager = MYLocationManager()` and replace it with `@EnvironmentObject var location: MYLocationManager` and then create your `CoreLocationView_NeedsEnv` view like this `CoreLocationView_NeedsEnv().environment(\.managedObjectContext, container.viewContext).environmentObject(MYLocationManager())`, it doesn't work?

Comment: @K.Law I accidentally based that code on Fabian's answer. It would still apply to your original code, however. Replace the `@ObservedObject` line with the `@EnvironmentObject` line and then pass the environment object to your `ContentView` when creating it.

Comment: I have tried it on my code and Fabian's code and it produces the same error.    libswiftCore.dylib`_swift_runtime_on_report:
->  0x1a2cf728c <+0>: ret    Thread 1: Fatal error: No observable object of type MYLocationManager.Type found.

Comment: More info from the console:   Type may be missing as an ancestor of this view.: file /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/Monoceros/Monoceros-24.4/Core/EnvironmentObject.swift, line 161
2019-08-22 16:11:01.950065-0600 New1Thing[476:35235] Fatal error: No observable object of type MYLocationManager.Type found.
A View.environmentObject(_:) for MYLocationManager.Type may be missing as an ancestor of this view.: file /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/Monoceros/Monoceros-24.4/Core/EnvironmentObject.swift, line 161

Comment: @graycampbell  I got it to work!  In the SceneDelegate I used: let myLocationManager = MYLocationManager()  and then:  .environmentObject(myLocationManager) on the window.rootViewController.

Comment: @K.Law I figured that’s probably what you were missing. Glad we could help!