# How do I access data from a child view as the parent view at any time in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, combine

I'm new to SwiftUI and understand that I may need to implement EnvironmentObject in some way, but I'm not sure how in this case.

This is the `Trade` class

```
class Trade {
    var teamsSelected: [Team]

    init(teamsSelected: [Team]) {
        self.teamsSelected = teamsSelected
    }
}
```

This is the child view. It has an instance `trade` from the `Trade` class. There is a button that appends 1 to array `teamsSelected`.

```
struct TeamRow: View {
    var trade: Trade

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.trade.teamsSelected.append(1)
        }) {
            Text("Button")
        }
    }
}
```

This is the parent view. As you can see, I pass `trade` into the child view `TeamRow`. I want `trade` to be in sync with `trade` in `TeamRow` so that I can then pass `trade.teamsSelected` to `TradeView`.

```
struct TeamSelectView: View {
    var trade = Trade(teamsSelected: [])

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack{
                NavigationLink(destination: TradeView(teamsSelected: trade.teamsSelected)) {
                   Text("Trade")
                }

                List {
                    ForEach(teams) { team in
                        TeamRow(trade: self.trade)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

I've taken your code and changed some things to illustrate how SwiftUI works in order to give you a better understanding of how to use `ObservableObject`, `@ObservedObject`, `@State`, and `@Binding`.

One thing to mention up front - `@ObservedObject` is currently broken when trying to run SwiftUI code on a physical device running iOS 13 Beta 6, 7, or 8. I answered a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57421554/cant-use-observedobject-on-real-iphone/57421882#57421882) that goes into that in more detail and explains how to use `@EnvironmentObject` as a workaround.

---

Let's first take a look at `Trade`. Since you're looking to pass a `Trade` object between views, change properties on that `Trade` object, and then have those changes reflected in every view that uses that `Trade` object, you'll want to make `Trade` an `ObservableObject`. I've added an extra property to your `Trade` class purely for illustrative purposes that I'll explain later. I'm going to show you two ways to write an `ObservableObject` - the verbose way first to see how it works, and then the concise way.

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class Trade: ObservableObject {
    let objectWillChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()

    var name: String {
        willSet {
            self.objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }

    var teamsSelected: [Int] {
        willSet {
            self.objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }

    init(name: String, teamsSelected: [Int]) {
        self.name = name
        self.teamsSelected = teamsSelected
    }
}
```

When we conform to `ObservableObject`, we have the option to write our own `ObservableObjectPublisher`, which I've done by importing `Combine` and creating a `PassthroughSubject`. Then, when I want to publish that my object is about to change, I can call `self.objectWillChange.send()` as I have on `willSet` for `name` and `teamsSelected`.

This code can be shortened significantly, however. `ObservableObject` automatically synthesizes an object publisher, so we don't actually have to declare it ourselves. We can also use `@Published` to declare our properties that should send a publisher event instead of using `self.objectWillChange.send()` in `willSet`.

```swift
import SwiftUI

class Trade: ObservableObject {
    @Published var name: String
    @Published var teamsSelected: [Int]

    init(name: String, teamsSelected: [Int]) {
        self.name = name
        self.teamsSelected = teamsSelected
    }
}
```

Now let's take a look at your `TeamSelectView`, `TeamRow`, and `TradeView`. Keep in mind once again that I've made some changes (and added an example `TradeView`) just to illustrate a couple of things.

```swift
struct TeamSelectView: View {
    @ObservedObject var trade = Trade(name: "Name", teamsSelected: [])
    @State var teams = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack{
                NavigationLink(destination: TradeView(trade: self.trade)) {
                    Text(self.trade.name)
                }

                List {
                    ForEach(self.teams, id: \.self) { team in
                        TeamRow(trade: self.trade)
                    }
                }
                Text("\(self.trade.teamsSelected.count)")
            }
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button("+", action: {
                self.teams.append(1)
            }))
        }
    }
}
```

```swift
struct TeamRow: View {
    @ObservedObject var trade: Trade

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.trade.teamsSelected.append(1)
        }) {
            Text("Button")
        }
    }
}
```

```swift
struct TradeView: View {
    @ObservedObject var trade: Trade

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(self.trade.teamsSelected.count)")
            TextField("Trade Name", text: self.$trade.name)
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

Let's first look at `@State var teams`. We use `@State` for simple value types - `Int`, `String`, basic `structs` - or collections of simple value types. `@ObservedObject` is used for objects that conform to `ObservableObject`, which we use for data structures that are more complex than just `Int` or `String`.

What you'll notice with `@State var teams` is that I've added a navigation bar item that will append a new item to the `teams` array when pressed, and since our `List` is generated by iterating through that `teams` array, our view re-renders and adds a new item to our `List` whenever the button is pressed. That's a very basic example of how you would use `@State`.

Next, we have our `@ObservedObject var trade`. You'll notice that I'm not really doing anything different than you were originally. I'm still creating an instance of my `Trade` class and passing that instance between my views. But since it's now an `ObservableObject`, and we're using `@ObservedObject`, our views will now all receive publisher events whenever the `Trade` object changes and will automatically re-render their views to reflect those changes.

The last thing I want to point out is the `TextField` I created in `TradeView` to update the `Trade` object's `name` property.

```swift
TextField("Trade Name", text: self.$trade.name)
```

The `$` character indicates that I'm passing a binding to the text field. This means that any changes `TextField` makes to `name` will be reflected in my `Trade` object. You can do the same thing yourself by declaring `@Binding` properties that allow you to pass bindings between views when you are trying to sync state between your views without passing entire objects.

While I changed your `TradeView` to take `@ObservedObject var trade`, you could simply pass `teamsSelected` to your trade view as a binding like this - `TradeView(teamsSelected: self.$trade.teamsSelected)` - as long as your `TradeView` accepts a binding. To configure your `TradeView` to accept a binding, all you would have to do is declare your `teamsSelected` property in `TradeView` like this:

```swift
@Binding var teamsSelected: [Team]
```

And lastly, if you run into issues with using `@ObservedObject` on a physical device, you can refer to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57421554/cant-use-observedobject-on-real-iphone/57421882#57421882) for an explanation of how to use `@EnvironmentObject` as a workaround.

Comment: Fantastic, explained very well.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `@Binding` and `@State` / `@Published` in Combine.
In other words, use a `@Binding` property in Child View and bind it with a `@State` or a `@Published` property in Parent View as following.

```
struct ChildView: View {
    @Binding var property1: String
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            TextField(placeholderTitle, text: $property1)
        }        
    }
}
struct PrimaryTextField_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        PrimaryTextField(value: .constant(""))
    }
}
```

```
struct ParentView: View{
    @State linkedProperty: String = ""
    //...
        ChildView(property1: $linkedProperty)
    //...
}
```

or if you have a `@Publilshed` property in your viewModel(`@ObservedObject`), then use it to bind the state like `ChildView(property1: $viewModel.publishedProperty)`.

Answer (score 0):

firstly thanks a lot to graycampbell for giving me a better understanding! However, my understanding does not seem to work out completely. I have a slightly different case which I'm not fully able to solve.

I've already asked my question in a separate thread, but I want to add it here as well, because it somehow fits the topic: [Reading values from list of toggles in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60836499/reading-values-from-list-of-toggles-in-swiftui)

Maybe somebody of you guys can help me with this. The main difference to the initial post if this topic is, that I have to collect Data from each `GameGenerationRow` in the `GameGenerationView` and then hand it over to another View.