# SwiftUI View observes its property passed from parent View

Tags: swift, swiftui

How do I write to observe the property passed from parent View?

```
struct ParentView: View {
    @State var prop = "a"

    var body: some View {
        ChildView(prop: prop)
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {
    var prop: String {    // When the "prop" changed, do something.
        didSet {
            print(prop)   // not work
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        Text(prop)
    }
}
```

Comment: have you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57617476/how-do-i-access-data-from-a-child-view-as-the-parent-view-at-any-time-in-swiftui?

Comment: In case of `prop` changed in `ParentView` the `ChildView` will be just recreated, so you don't need to observe anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ParentView` creates a new instance of `ChildView` with a new value of `prop` every time when `@State var prop = "a"` change.

You can create a custom init and check a new value:

```swift
struct ChildView: View {
    var prop: String
    
    init(prop: String) {
        self.prop = prop
        print(prop) // <-- here
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(prop)
    }
}
```